# do-while loop not working as it should

Tags: java, do-while

Ok so basically I am having trouble finding out why this is not working as I think it should, and need help getting to the right output. I have tried messing with this format a few ways, but nothing works, and I really don't understand why. Here are the instructions, followed by my source for it:

### INSTRUCTIONS

Write a loop that reads strings from standard input where the string is either "land", "air", or "water". The loop terminates when "xxxxx" (five x characters) is read in. Other strings are ignored. After the loop, your code should print out 3 lines: the first consisting of the string "land:" followed by the number of "land" strings read in, the second consisting of the string "air:" followed by the number of "air" strings read in, and the third consisting of the string "water:" followed by the number of "water" strings read in. Each of these should be printed on a separate line.

ASSUME the availability of a variable,  stdin , that references a  Scanner object associated with standard input.

### SOURCE:

```
int land = 0;
int air = 0;
int water = 0;

do
{
     String stdInput = stdin.next();
        if (stdInput.equalsIgnoreCase("land"))
        {
            land++;
        }else if (stdInput.equalsIgnoreCase("air"))
        {
            air++;
        }else if (stdInput.equalsIgnoreCase("water"))
        {
            water++;
        }
}while (stdin.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxx") == false); // I think the issue is here, I just dont't know why it doesn't work this way
System.out.println("land: " + land);
System.out.println("air: " + air);
System.out.println("water: " + water);
```

Comment: what is not working? tell your expected and actual output!

Comment: what's your stdin type ?

Comment: Another "not working as it should" question

Answer (score 5):

You are storing user info in `stdInput` but your while checks `stdin`. Try this way

```
String stdInput = null;

do {
    stdInput = stdin.next();

    //your ifs....

} while (!stdInput.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxx"));
```

Answer (score 1):

### This Works:)

**I just submitted this code to codelab and it works just fine.**

Write a loop that reads strings  from standard input where the string  is either "land", "air", or "water". The loop terminates  when "xxxxx" (five x characters ) is read in. Other strings  are ignored. After the loop, your code should print out 3 lines: the first consisting of the string  "land:" followed by the number of "land" strings  read in, the second consisting of the string  "air:" followed by the number of "air" strings  read in, and the third consisting of the string  "water:" followed by the number of "water" strings  read in. Each of these should be printed on a separate line.

```
int land = 0;
int air = 0;
int water = 0;
String word = "";
while(!(word.equals("xxxxx"))) {
 word = stdin.next();
if(word.equals("land")) {
    land++;
}else if(word.equals("air")) {
    air++;
}else if(word.equals("water")) {
    water++;
} 
}
System.out.println("land:" + land);
System.out.println("air:" + air);
System.out.println("water:" + water);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `stdInput.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxx") == false` instead of `stdin.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxx") == false`.

Comment: SO TRUE LOL! OMG I hate myself but that kind of double checking is all part of the game, thanks for pointing that out! FYI got it working as intended now!

Answer (score 0):

You are right - the problem is where you indicated. The solution is to *not* read again from stdin:

Also, you must declare the `stdInput` *before* the loop so its scope reaches the while condition:

```
String stdInput = null;
do {
    stdInput = stdin.next();
    // rest of code the same
} while (!stdInput.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxx"));
```

An alternate way would be a for loop:

```
for (String stdInput = stdin.next(); !stdInput.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxx"); stdInput = stdin.next()) {
    // rest of code the same
}
```

Comment: AHHH and I see that the ! goes BEFORE the boolean expression for the string as well, don't recall our teacher mentioning THAT to us! I see how that would work though! Ill try these out brb...

Comment: It's good coding practice to never compare a boolean with a boolean constant (it just adds more code for no value). Instead always use the boolean by itself, or put a `!` before it for the negative.

Comment: Ya that really helped, didn't even notice my original boolean was wrong to begin with! Got everything squared away now thanks for the help